# Variable for getting absolute path in windows batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have following script to list out all the files, recursively from a directory, having a `.phtml` extension.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f %%G in ('forfiles /s /m *.phtml /c "cmd /c echo @relpath"') do echo %%G >> listoffiles.txt
endlocal
exit
```

It lists out only relative path to files. The above script is running from an intermediate location, so I am not getting full paths in `@relpath` variable.

Also I am getting quotes in the result lines, which I want to remove.

I want to get absolute path to those files with a few code changes as possible, if a global-variable is available which can be used in my code then it's best for me, as I am not much of Windows batch scripter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I am not getting full paths in the `@relpath` variable.

> also I am getting quotes in the result lines, which I want to remove.

The following batch file does what you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%G in ('forfiles /s /m *.phtml /c "cmd /c echo @path"') do (
  set _name=%%G
  rem strip the quotes
  echo !_name:~1,-1! >> listoffiles.txt
  )
endlocal
exit
```

Notes:

- Uses `@path` (Full path of the file) instead of `@relpath` (Relative path of the file).
- Uses a variable `substring` expression to remove the quotes (`:~1,-1` removes the first and last characters from the variable string).
- Uses `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` so that variables are updated correctly in the `for` loop.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [forfiles](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) - Select a file (or set of files) and execute a command on each file. Batch processing.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).